# Css3 Adjacent sibling combinator

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector)

In a list, if there are 3 list items:

```
1 <li>..</li>
2 <li>..</li>
3 <li>..</li>
```

It is possible to use, for example li+li to get the one after the targeted list item.

My question: How to get the one BEFORE the targeted item?

Comment: How about using jquery?
you can do that with .prev() function, and add a class to the previous item.. 

<code>
    $("#selected-li").prev("li").addClass("something");
</code>

Comment: Thank you very much, I might do so if CSS is not enough.

Comment: The adjacent sibling combinator is not new to CSS3.

Comment: @Bullocks, try reading TO understand before deeming anything as duplicate. You're making yourself look funny.

Answer (score 1):

`li ~ li`

**EDIT**: Oh, now that I think of it, what you want is not supported in CSS3, but hopefully will get into CSS4 with the feature called subject selector. It is the `$` sign, and indicates which rule will be the selector's subject. I recently also needed it to select parents of a given match (formerly proposed as :parent selector).

An example would be `$li + li`. Unfortunately there is no support yet and no known schedule.

Comment: I have read that page and tried it all extensively before asking. That one works for all the ones coming after as well, unlike + which only applies for 1 coming after. Thank you though.

Comment: Oh, okay, misunderstood the question, updated answer.

Comment: I agree with @PéterVarga as I don't think this will be possible via CSS until CSS4 selectors are implemented.

Comment: The subject selector is no longer `$` as of January 2012.